# How to get entered information into pre-written set of quotes?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I have what I believe to be a very simple problem, but I can't figure it out. I have a text box that people can enter names into, which works fine. However, I need the text entered into this text box to appear into a set of pre-written strings of text later in the form. Example:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name Here" autofocus>
<hr>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var quoteSource=[

        {
            quote: "NAME got distracted by a butterfly. Once they re-focused on their task, they found:",
        },
        {
            quote:"NAME found absolutely nothing on their adventure.",
        }

    ];
```

I ran around the web trying out different things like this; I see now though that I had the code confused. I am in the process of trying to learn code myself and It's - obviously - proving difficult!

```
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('click', function(){
quote: (item.quote).replace('NAME', $('name').val())
      });
```

I need the name entered to appear in the 'NAME' section of the 'quote' area. Can anyone help? Thank you!!

Comment: You'll need to show more of the code you've attempted. There are many, many different ways to do what you want to do (as I was writing this, I see someone suggested one of those ways), so you'd have to be clearly going in a particular direction before one could be chosen. A lot depends on the timing of how this is supposed to work -- are the quotes displayed all of the time, and supposed to change immediately as the name is typed? Do you someone make the user signify that they've finished entering their name, and then show the quotes after?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not  a free code writing service. The objective is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when your code doesn't work as expected

Comment: So sorry - It's my first time posting I wan't entirely sure what to do! I will add what I'd attempted previously.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var quoteSource = [
    {
      quote: "NAME got distracted by a butterfly. Once they re-focused on their task, they found:",
    },
    {
      quote: "NAME found absolutely nothing on their adventure.",
    }
  ];
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#name').on('keyup', function() {
    var quoteSourceNew = [];
    for(var item of quoteSource) {
      quoteSourceNew.push({
        quote: (item.quote).replace(/NAME/, $('#name').val())
      });
    }
    console.log(quoteSourceNew);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name Here" autofocus>
```

Comment: Keeps adding to array every key event without removing previous entries. Might make sense mapping new array each time

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Name = 'John';
var quoteSource = [{
    quote: "NAME got distracted by a butterfly. Once they re-focused on their task, they found:",
  },
  {
    quote: "NAME found absolutely nothing on their adventure.",
  }
]

document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('input', function(){
  Name = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('quote').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * quoteSource.length );
  console.clear();
  console.log( quoteSource[rand].quote.replace(/NAME/g, Name) );
});
```

```html
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name Here" autofocus>
<br><br>
<button id="quote">Add Quote</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is these what you need?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var quoteSource=[

    {
        quote: "NAME got distracted by a butterfly. Once they re-focused on their task, they found:",
    },
  {
        quote:"NAME found absolutely nothing on their adventure.",
    }

];

document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('change',e=>{
  quoteSource.forEach(quotei=>quotei.quote = quotei.quote.replace('NAME',e.target.value));
});

});
```

Comment: Thought about same thing, but it will work only once)